# Representation of progressive uncertainty reduction

Tags: forecasting, decision-theory

I'm interested in programming a multistage problem by means of a dynamic programming approach, following Bellman's optimality principle. That is, the problem is solved in a number of stages backwards. At each stage, a decision must be made by observing a variable (the price). If the price of the last stage is adequate, we take a position at any other stage in which a combination of other known values occur. At the last stage, its value is perfectly known. But at any other given step the price value is uncertain, and this uncertainty grows as we go away from the last stage, where the value was completely known.
Any idea on how we can model the decision at each stage, based on an uncertainty that grows as we are farther form the final step? At each step we know every parameter involved with the decision, except the final price. How is the decision made?

Comment: Read a book on Stochastic Dynamic Programming.

Comment: Thank you for your useless response. For your information, I've already read and programmed quite a bit about DP in the field of swing options. Maybe it has been my fault to not appropriately pose the question, which is not related to the mechanics of DP but to the incorporation of forecast errors in the decision process. Anyway, it is because of rude answers like yours that excellent discussion groups like StackExchange some times (fortunately few) loss their collaborating nature.

Comment: Perhaps you've read a lot, but you haven't understood.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand. That's why I entered this forum as thousands more of people do in the hope of not finding a know-it-all. But I did understand the politeness lessons in the kindergarten. Others (you) not so fortunate to understand. Sorry for you. Good luck in your wisdom heaven.

Comment: Just for the record, if anyone needs help in this sense, I found a solution to my problem starting at Hausman's work in http://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/mnsc.16.2.b93, "Sequential Decision Problems: A Model to Exploit Existing Forecasters." Just so simple to have been pointed to this reference. Hope it helps other people, without tripping on Mr. Stone.